# Reducing number of cores while VM is suspended

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machines, vmware-workstation, vmware-fusion

I have an Ubuntu 16.04 64bit VM which I run off of an external SSD.
I allocated higher cores (8) on a PC with 16 cores. I suspended the state and brought back the drive home to run the VM on a Macbook pro which can only give 4 cores to the VM. Since the VM is in suspended state, VMWare fusion doesn't allow me to change the cores nor can I power it on to shut it down.
Is there a way to force change the number of cores while the state is still suspended or is there a way to pull the plug on this VM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change CPU cores only on turned off VM. You could force shutdown your VM as described in [this article](https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1006215).